# Customer portal self registration error: "The account associated with this portal has no owner"

Tags: force.com

I'm working through the tutorial here to enable a Customer Portal for my site:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites

As suggested, I got an existing account ID (I used my own account, which is an admin account) and pasted it into my SiteRegisterController, so it looks like this:

```
public with sharing class SiteRegisterController
{   
     private static Id PORTAL_ACCOUNT_ID = '00590000000aB8l'; // ID of my admin account

     // snip ...
}
```

But after I fill in all the details and hit siubmit on the self-registration page at /SiteRegister, it responds:

> Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator
> has been alerted.
>
> The account associated with this portal has no owner

The error email that gets sent to me when this occurs says:

> Catalog registration accountId parameter value is not valid

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the id `00590000000aB8l` is a user id (starts with `005`), not an account id (starts with `001`). Try creating a new Account (on the Account tab, not in Setup), enabling portals on that Account, and then uses its `001...` id instead.